# Creating a specific Navbar with Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, navbar

**I have a concept of a navbar in mind**. On Big Screens it should be in one line with the header of the website but on mobile devices it should be under the header.

[image: This is how it should look]

I already tried to get it done, but I wasn't able to figure it out. I want to realize this with Bootstrap.

### Edit

I only figured out how to implement a standart navbar I don't know where to start with the concept!

### Edit 2

Figured out that with

```
<nav class="flex-column-lg">
```

I could do it the other way around, but still no clue.

Comment: post your code what you tried till now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should do the trick.

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light row">
    <div class="col-sm col-md-2">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">MyWebsite</a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm col-md-10 navbar-nav d-inline-flex flex-row justify-content-around" >
      <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">img-link</a>
      <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">img-link</a>
      <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">img-link</a>
    </div>
  </nav>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you so  much this is exactly what i wanted to do!!! Really appreciate it! Edit:Just want to say that I had to add ```class="img-fluid"``` in the image link

Comment: No problem! It's the first time I'm answering a question here, feels good :P

Comment: Nice! Welcome to StackOverFlow! :-)